# Document Library Icons

Tags: document-library, document, custom-form

For SharePoint (2007/2010) if I want to build custom UI to render a Document Library (pretty it up a bit), is there a field on a Document Library SPListItem that tells me the link to the document icon?  For example, when I display an Excel file, the little Excel graphic is shown?  If not available on the SPListItem as a field, is there a way to access it through some standard API?

Answer (score 1):

This is the chap you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.iconurl.aspx